How to automatically use USB for file transfers (on my PC only)
When I connect my Google Pixel 6 to my Windows 11 laptop via a USB cable, it only charges by default and does not allow me to transfer files without first enabling file transfers on the handheld, in USB preferences.
Unfortunately, every time I undock my laptop then redock, I need to reconfigure that setting, which constantly resets to "No data transfer". I am not alone in this situation, as this forum post (and another question) shows, but this happens on a fully up-to-date Android 15 (and takes more than 5 s each time).
Is there no way to remember the value of "Use USB for" with my laptop? Note that I am not an Android developer and store potentially confidential data on the handheld, so granting an unsafe allow all as Developer options lets me configure (regardless of which computer is plugged) is not an option.

The setting is on the phone, which you carry with you.  I dont see a problem here.

USB client devices can't identify the host. Even with the new spec "USB-C-Auth" the authentication would only work the other way round. The only secure, always active access between PC and Android phone via USB is Android Debug bridge (adb). However that requires special drivers and (command-line) tools on PC side.
